# running asynchronous Process without wait

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following command which runs a Symfony2 Process:

```
class UpdateShopsCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('backgroundtask:updateshop')
            ->setDescription('Update paying shops pictures and bio')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $container = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer();
        $shopsNeededToBeUpdated = $this->getShopsNeedToBeUpdated();
        foreach ($shopsNeededToBeUpdated as $shop) {
            //start a process here
            var_dump('updating shop ' . $shop->getUsername());
            $process = new Process('app/console backgroundtask:refreshuserinfo ' . $shop->getUserid() . ' false --env=' . $this->get('kernel')->getEnvironment());
            $process->setTimeout(3600);
            $process->start();
            $process->wait(function ($type, $buffer) {
                if (Process::ERR === $type) {
                    echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
                } else {
                    echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
                }
            });
        }

        $output->writeln('Finished updating shops');
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly if I had the wait function in it. However I do not wish to have the `wait` in it, because wait blocks the thread and now it's not async, just want to start the process async. However when I do so, it is as if the process was never started. Why is this? Do I really need the wait for an async process? How do I know that it is actually running?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?